# How to send list of payloads to RV adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to send list of payloads to my adapter. It will allow me to set text at certain item of RV. I do it in such way:

```
val position = data.getIntExtra("listPosition", 0)
val status = data.getIntExtra("new_status", 0)


val payload = mutableListOf<Any>()
payload.add(0, 3)
payload.add(1, status)

adapter.notifyItemChanged(position, payload)
```

but in adapter I receive such list:
[[3,3]]

Receiving place at adapter:

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotesHolder, position: Int, payloads: List<Any>) {
        if (payloads.isNotEmpty()) {
            Timber.i(payloads.toString())
            when (payloads[0]) {
             ... 
             3->{
                    holder.statusTv.text = "some text"
             }
            }
        }
}
```

maybe someone knows why does it happen and how I can  send several commands to my adapter?

Comment: Your payload is list with index 0 always is 3 and index 1 maybe status equals 3 too. What is value of status?

Comment: @CôngHải,  for example 3, it can be any int number, but I can't understand how to send it to onbindViewholder :(

Comment: When you call adapter.notifyItemChanged it will be trigger callback onBinhViewHolder with your payload.

Comment: with one payload, not with a list of payloads

Comment: You can call notifyItemRangeChanged with your payload list

Comment: at payloads function I receive such list `[[3,3]]` it is bad I think

Comment: You can notify item change with loop. Instead of payload list pass one by one payload to position